# When typing single or double qoutation mark i get a different symbol

Tags: emacs, keyboard

I've recently started learning Emacs and I like it a lot, except one thing. When I type single **`'`** or double **`"`** quotation marks I get different symbol displayed, i.e. **`´`** and **`¨`** respectively.

I tried to alter variable `set-keyboard-coding-system` but it didn't help. I've also googled a lot on how to change this behaviour... unsuccessfully.

Comment: Please specify how you start Emacs, saying whether you use it as a GUI or terminal, etc. And start it without any init file, e.g. `emacs -Q`, to be sure something in your init file isn't causing the problem.

Comment: @Drew I start Emacs as GUI just typing "emacs" in linux terminal without any init file configuration

Comment: I also tried to reinstall emacs and it didn't help

Comment: Hopefully someone will have a suggestion. If not, delete the question here and post it on emacs.StackExchange instead. Or send the question as a mail to help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org.

Comment: "in linux terminal". what terminal? be specific. what linux distro are you using? be specific. what desktop are you using? be specific

Comment: @nega I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on Windows 11 via WSL 2 (my machine is Huawei Matebook D15). As for terminal, i just open cmd, create new tab and choose Ubuntu terminal from the dropdown list.

Comment: disable "smart quotes" in windows.

Comment: Thank you guys! While searching for how to disable "smart quotes" on Windows 11 I decided to change US international keyboard layout to ordinary US and it worked!

Comment: I suggest --OP or @nega-- to add the solution as an answer (with the details appropriate for an answer.) This would help future visitors of this thread.